# jQuery - Getting center of link

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

I'm trying to build a popover control for a website I'm working on, but I can't get the positioning right. I've tried various ways of getting the hyperlink's center, but it's always a little off.

I don't want to hardcode the coordinates because I need this to be universal, it needs to work with any link that I may use the popover on in the future.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my current method:

```
$('#whatsthis').click(function(e) 
{
    var _linkLocation = $(this).offset();
    $('#helpTip').css('position','absolute');

    $('#helpTip').css('left', _linkLocation.left - $(this).width()/2);

    $('#helpTip').fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

..and here's the current output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
$('#whatsthis').click(function(e)  {
    var _linkLocation = $(this).offset(), $helpTip = $('#helpTip');
    $helpTip.offset({ 
        'left': _linkLocation.left + $(this).width()/2 - $helpTip.width()/2,
        'top': _linkLocation.top + $(this).height()
    }).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This doesn't work though. The popover completely disappears and is replaced by a large whitespace of the popover's size below the link. See it for yourself: http://www.writeitstudios.com/myaccount/store

Comment: If I add `$('#helpTip').css('position','absolute');` (which was missing from your code), the popover is in the right place, but even further away from the center of the link than it was before.

Comment: @Prypiat Try my fixed version, the previous one missed the width of the helpTip self.

Comment: Thank you! All I needed to do was to add `$helpTip.css('position','absolute');` to your code and all works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Use parenthesis to ensure you get the delta before you half it.

```
(_linkLocation.left - $(this).width()) / 2
```

Otherwise, operator precedence will bind the `/ 2` to the result of the width first and give you incorrect results.

Comment: This should not be the problem, he wants to place the center of tip to the center of the link.